# Really slow 3D viewport render preview with gtx-970

Tags: rendering

I do have a new computer (much better than the previous one) and the preview rendering in cycles render is for taking REALLY long time, 5 samples/sec.

I do have Intel i7, 16gb RAM, MSI gtx 970 (4gb), so no idea why it takes so long time.

Any help? Tried changing to CUDA, changed both in user preferences and in the "render" tab.
[image]

Comment: Go to blenchmark.com and test your system. Compare that to other GTX 970 machines to make sure you know what "reasonable" is for your setup. Also post here what your time is, so that we have some more diagnostic data.

Comment: If you can upload your blender file, that might also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you switch to GPU rendering you need to adjust the render tile size. CPU requires small tile sizes, GPU works better with large ones. Start with a size like 128x128 or 265x256 and see if that makes it better. Make a few test to find an optimal setting for your system

Comment: where do I change that?

Comment: In the performance section http://i.stack.imgur.com/88Py1.jpg

Comment: Yes, but I mean during the preview render

Comment: Sorry, I'm terrible at guessing. Please edit your question and ask what you really mean...

Comment: Can you add some screen shots of your render panels settings?

Comment: @Omnitored Unfortunately, you can't change the tile settings for the rendered preview. It uses one tile and one GPU, regardless. I suspect there's a setting you've left unchanged, but it's hard to tell which one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable GPU compute in two places:

User Preferences (Which I think you've already done:

[image: File->User Preferences->System]

And the render panel:

[image]

I'm running a GTX970 and enjoying the performance. On a simple scene it zips through all 32 samples in the preview in about a second.

-- edit ---

Just say that you mentioned you'd enabled it in both places. I'll leave this post here in case someone else comes along.